# Can't Access JSON Attribute

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm having trouble getting python to access the "data" attribute in a JSON file. I'm trying to write an element (text) within a JSON dump to a csv file:

```
import requests
import json
import csv

BEARER_TOKEN = "xyz"


#Create list of search terms
f = open("search_terms.txt", "r")

terms = []
for line in f:
  stripped_line = line.strip()
  terms.append(stripped_line)

#define search twitter function
def search_twitter(query, tweet_fields, bearer_token = BEARER_TOKEN):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}

    url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query={}&{}".format(
        query, tweet_fields
    )
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

    print(response.status_code)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()

#twitter fields to be returned by api call
tweet_fields = "tweet.fields=text"

#twitter api call
with open("tweets.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(["Search Term", "Tweet"])

    for term in terms:
        json_response = search_twitter(query=term, tweet_fields=tweet_fields, bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN)
        print(json_response)
        for entry in json_response['data']:
            tweet = entry['text']
            tweet_lower = tweet.lower()
            writer.writerow([term, tweet])
```

Here's what the JSON dump looks like:

```
{'data': [{'id': '1440783749277356032', 'text': "@varindersingh24 Every time I go into a store, and I will continue to. I'm not worried that I'll get Covid, I'm worried that I will unknowingly have it, and pass it on to someone it could possibly kill"}, {'id': '1440783749231251460', 'text': 'RT @PAbeywardena: RM of @bts_bighit gave remarks on behalf of BTS to celebrate South Korean art at the @metmuseum - the group is visiting N…'}, {'id': '1440783749180903424', 'text': 'The crazy thing is that I have three flights tomorrow. I cannot afford to have this covid test mess me up'}, {'id': '1440783749147344897', 'text': '@loichervepublic @Senat ⚠️⚠️⚠️Arrêtez tout!!!\n\n"Covid-19 : le vaccin Pfizer-BioNTech est "sûr" pour les enfants de 5 à 11 ans, selon une étude des deux laboratoires" \n#NiBétailNiCobaye\n\n]'}, {'id': '1440783749004685316', 'text': 'Michigan Reports 6,079 New COVID-19 Cases, 81 Deaths '}, {'id': '1440783748887298057', 'text': '@SaenaLife Ugh it went something like this:\n\nAntivaxxer: I don’t need a vaccine. I’ll just get COVID and if I die I die\nMe: ok I guess you can die then \nTwitter: }, {'id': '1440783748497174539', 'text': 'Supposed to be in Austin next week, but of course everything is up in the air now BECAUSE OF COVID. I just bought my plane tickets and now I may not be able to go??? Anyway, here are some shitty quality photos of myself because I am who I am. '}, {'id': '1440783748329459718', 'text': '@RAIDER_UCE Was it Covid?'}, {'id': '1440783748149100549', 'text': 'RT @lolaescreva: Hj ficamos sabendo q o médico negacionista e anti-vacina Anthony Wong e a mãe do Luciano Hang tomaram cloroquina e morrera…'}, {'id': '1440783748002238464', 'text': 'RT @TorontoStar: Police in Quebec say they are looking for a man who is alleged to have repeatedly punched a nurse in the face because he w…'}], 'meta': {'newest_id': '1440783749277356032', 'oldest_id': '1440783748002238464', 'result_count': 10, 'next_token': 'b26v89c19zqg8o3fpds60sun1e73uhts8q2rarv3ilgfx'}}
```

I'm not getting any error messages, the csv just isn't populating with anything but the first row. I'd like for the values of the first column to be the search term (in the list of terms) and the second column to be the "text" attribute of JSON, or the Tweet.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a JSON dump, that's a Python dictionary.

Comment: Seems like you need to put a breakpoint on the `for entry in json_response['data']:` line and then see what `entry` contains.